# Get data from ESP32 over video in OpenCV - Python => freezing video

Tags: python, opencv, pyserial, esp32

I am working in a project where I need to show external data (from an ESP32 with an BME280 sensor) over a video in real time. I'm using opencv in Python to get the video from my webcam.
The video working fine until I put the code for get the sensor data over the video, it turn very slow and freezing every 1/2 second (related with the delay in ESP32 code).
Too I found that timeout (in python code) has a very important role... if I put it in 0 the video flow fine, but the data cant show properly.
So I understand that readline() in my code has a blocking behaviour, if it doesn't receiver the last character of the line ("\n"), it can't to continue in the loop "while".
The question is, how I can to redefine my code for avoid that??

Python code:

```
import serial
import cv2 as cv
import datetime

cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Camera cannot open")
    exit()
    
    
arduino = serial.Serial('COM7', baudrate=115200, timeout = 0)

while True:

    ret , frame= cap.read()
    
    if not ret:
        print("void frame")
        break
    
    #reading line from ESP32

    rawString = str(arduino.readline())
    print(rawString)
    # replace "\r" and "\n" for ""

    rawString = rawString.replace("\\r\\n'","")
    rawString = rawString.replace("b'","")
    
    #Add data to video (real time and sensor)
    hora = str(datetime.datetime.now())
    print(type(hora))
    font = cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    cv.putText(frame, hora,(10,50), font, 0.8,(255,0,0),2,cv.LINE_AA)
    cv.putText(frame, rawString,(10,80), font, 0.8,(255,0,0),2,cv.LINE_AA)

    #show the video
    cv.imshow("Video", frame)
    
    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

arduino.close()
cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

ESP32 code:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Adafruit_BME280.h>



Adafruit_BME280 bme; // I2C

unsigned long delayTime;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println(F("BME280 test"));

  bool status;

  // default settings
  // (you can also pass in a Wire library object like &Wire2)
  status = bme.begin(0x77);  
  if (!status) {
    Serial.println("Could not find a valid BME280 sensor, check wiring!");
    while (1);
  }

  Serial.println("-- Default Test --");
  delayTime = 500;

}


void loop() { 
  printValues();
  delay(delayTime);
}

void printValues() {

  Serial.println(bme.readTemperature());

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can immediately think of three ways to solve your problem.

A *simple solution* is to read the temperature from ESP32 in non-blocking way. As a useful hack you can be specify a very small timeout value when creating the pyserial port - say 1 ms. Then `readline()` will return nothing if there's no data in the serial buffer from the ESP32. When that happens, simply skip updating the variable `rawString`. See the [notes on `readline()`](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html#readline)

```
arduino = serial.Serial('COM7', baudrate=115200, timeout = 0.001)
...
    serialData = arduino.readline()
    if serialData:
        rawString = str(serialData)
...
```

Note that *correctly* implemented non-blocking reads would require setting the pyserial timeout parameter to 0 (as you have) and then reading anything the ESP32 has sent from pyserial's buffers byte by byte using [`read()`](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.read). You'd have to do the string processing to detect lines of sensor data yourself. It's not hard, so feel free to implement it yourself.

An *advanced solution* is threads. `readline()` is a blocking action, and such things should be run in a separate thread to avoid blocking your video processing. So feel free to spin up a new thread and run all communication with the ESP32 there. To propagate the temperature to your main thread, just use a shared global variable or something similar (whatever is the simplest numeric type with atomic updates in Python).

A *bad solution* is to update your ESP32 to send temperature updates with the same frequency as the frame rate of your video. I'd avoid this :)